# Get siblings between a range with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Its possible with jquery insert all elements with `class="sortable"`, the element with `class="header"` and the element with `class="page-break"` within the div with `id="page-0"` and so on for each new page?

I tried with:

```
$(".page").each(function(index) {
   $(this).prepend($(this).nextAll('.page'));
});
```

The problem is that `nextAll()` retrieves the element with `id="page-1"` , but I have no way to get all the above items that are between `page-0` and `page-1`.

The function
`$(this).siblings(".sortable")` .... not used for me because that gets all elements with `class="sortable"` that are between `page-2` and `page-3`, etc.

This is the target:

```
<div id="page-0" class="page">
    <div class="header herader-small-pdf"></div>
    <div class="sortable-0"></div>
    <div class="sortable-1"></div>
    <div class="sortable-2"></div>
    .....
    <div class="page-break"></div>
<div id="page-1" class="page">
    <div class="header herader-small-pdf"></div>
    <div class="sortable-x"></div>
    .....
    <div class="page-break"></div>
</div>
```

Its this possible?[image: current state]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)

```
$('.page').each(function(index) {
   $(this).prepend($(this).nextUntil('.page'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Iterate all `page` elements and `append()` each next element which is not having `page` class.

```
$(function(){
  $(".page").each(function() {
   var exitLoop = false;
   var nextElement = $(this).next();
   while(!exitLoop)
   {
      $(this).append(nextElement);
      nextElement = $(this).next();
      //check if next element has page class, then exit the loop
       if($(nextElement).length > 0 )
         exitLoop =  $(nextElement).hasClass('page');
       else
         exitLoop = true;
   }
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbgct04r/12/)**